# Unable to locate package after adding ppa:ondrej/php

Tags: php, vagrant, installation, apt

I've follow recommendations in [oerdnj package. Issue #56](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/56) in a new box without any luck.

It seems this package has some trouble with UTF-8 encoding. The owner has post instructions on how to force localization in the ppa to overcome this, but somehow a fresh install doesn't seem to resolve this

What am I missing?

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/precise64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise64' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: cpf_default_1496675342115_33230
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 3306 (guest) => 3306 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: 
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default: 
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.1
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
New release '14.04.5 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine.
Last login: Fri Sep 14 06:23:18 2012 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo su
root@precise64:/home/vagrant# apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease [55.7 kB]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease   
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease [55.7 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease [55.7 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                       
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [150 kB]    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release       
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [503 kB]       
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [4,643 B]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [57.9 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [3,032 B]         
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages [375 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [8,837 B]       
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [137 kB]        
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [10.5 kB]    
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages [741 kB]    
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages [10.9 kB]   
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages [145 kB]      
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15.4 kB]    
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages [288 kB]    
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [17.1 kB]    
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [745 kB]        
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3,367 B]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [377 kB]        
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15.3 kB]     
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [297 kB]        
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [17.3 kB]      
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex [208 B]              
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex [202 B]        
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex [202 B]        
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex [205 B]             
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources [5,922 B]                      
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources [28 B]                   
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources [44.2 kB]                  
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources [5,750 B]                
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages [6,477 B]           
Get:34 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [10.8 kB]     
Get:35 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [154 kB]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages [28 B]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages [46.3 kB]
Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages [5,419 B]    
Get:39 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages [6,478 B]            
Get:40 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages [28 B]         
Get:41 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages [46.1 kB]        
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [3,537 B]         
Get:43 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex [208 B]              
Get:44 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex [199 B]        
Get:45 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex [202 B]        
Get:46 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex [205 B]          
Get:47 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [5,413 B]      
Get:48 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en [188 kB]
Get:49 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex [202 B]                
Get:50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex [202 B]          
Get:51 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex [193 B]          
Get:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex [205 B]            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex                    
Get:53 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en [1,993 B]   
Get:54 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en [2,802 B]   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex      
Get:55 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en [344 kB]
Get:56 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en [93.2 kB]   
Get:57 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en [10.1 kB]                  
Get:58 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en [3,686 B]                    
Get:59 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en [174 kB]                       
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en [5,737 B]                        
Get:61 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en [4,852 B]                
Get:62 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en [28 B]                   
Get:63 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en [35.9 kB]                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en                                         
Fetched 5,297 kB in 2s (1,928 kB/s)                                                      
Reading package lists... Done
root@precise64:/home/vagrant# apt-get install -y python-software-properties software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  python-pycurl unattended-upgrades
Suggested packages:
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev python-pycurl-dbg bsd-mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pycurl python-software-properties software-properties-common unattended-upgrades
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 193 not upgraded.
Need to get 56.6 kB/106 kB of archives.
After this operation, 794 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main unattended-upgrades all 0.76ubuntu1.3 [24.7 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python-software-properties all 0.82.7.7 [23.5 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main software-properties-common all 0.82.7.7 [8,450 B]
Fetched 56.6 kB in 0s (214 kB/s)                 
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package unattended-upgrades.
(Reading database ... 51095 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking unattended-upgrades (from .../unattended-upgrades_0.76ubuntu1.3_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pycurl.
Unpacking python-pycurl (from .../python-pycurl_7.19.0-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-software-properties.
Unpacking python-software-properties (from .../python-software-properties_0.82.7.7_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package software-properties-common.
Unpacking software-properties-common (from .../software-properties-common_0.82.7.7_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up unattended-upgrades (0.76ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up python-pycurl (7.19.0-4ubuntu3) ...
Setting up python-software-properties (0.82.7.7) ...
Setting up software-properties-common (0.82.7.7) ...
root@precise64:/home/vagrant# apt-get install -y language-pack-en-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  language-pack-en
Recommended packages:
  firefox-locale-en
The following packages will be upgraded:
  language-pack-en language-pack-en-base
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 191 not upgraded.
Need to get 882 kB of archives.
After this operation, 143 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main language-pack-en all 1:12.04+20140106 [1,978 B]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main language-pack-en-base all 1:12.04+20140106 [880 kB]
Fetched 882 kB in 1s (605 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 51182 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace language-pack-en 1:12.04+20120801 (using .../language-pack-en_1%3a12.04+20140106_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement language-pack-en ...
Preparing to replace language-pack-en-base 1:12.04+20120801 (using .../language-pack-en-base_1%3a12.04+20140106_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement language-pack-en-base ...
Setting up language-pack-en (1:12.04+20140106) ...
Setting up language-pack-en-base (1:12.04+20140106) ...
Generating locales...
  en_AG.UTF-8... done
  en_AU.UTF-8... done
  en_BW.UTF-8... done
  en_CA.UTF-8... done
  en_DK.UTF-8... done
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
  en_HK.UTF-8... done
  en_IE.UTF-8... done
  en_IN.UTF-8... done
  en_NG.UTF-8... done
  en_NZ.UTF-8... done
  en_PH.UTF-8... done
  en_SG.UTF-8... done
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZA.UTF-8... done
  en_ZM.UTF-8... done
  en_ZW.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
root@precise64:/home/vagrant# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_PAPER="en_US"
LC_NAME="en_US"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
LC_ALL=en_US
root@precise64:/home/vagrant# export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
root@precise64:/home/vagrant# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
root@precise64:/home/vagrant# LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 Co-installable PHP versions: PHP 5.6, PHP 7.0, PHP 7.1 and most requested extensions are included.

PLEASE DON'T USE PHP 5.4 OR PHP 5.5. The PHP 5.5 and later are no longer supported with security updates, therefore they are not included in this repository.

You can get more information about the packages at https://deb.sury.org

BUGS&FEATURES: This PPA now has a issue tracker: https://deb.sury.org/#bug-reporting

PLEASE READ: If you like my work and want to give me a little motivation, please consider donating regularly: https://donate.sury.org/

WARNING: add-apt-repository is broken with non-UTF-8 locales, see https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/56 for workaround:

# LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmptF8yjV/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmptF8yjV/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key E5267A6C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmptF8yjV/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key E5267A6C: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ondřej Surý" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
root@precise64:/home/vagrant# apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   1024D/437D05B5 2004-09-12
uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
sub   2048g/79164387 2004-09-12

pub   1024D/FBB75451 2004-12-30
uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

pub   1024R/E5267A6C 2009-01-26
uid                  Launchpad PPA for Ondřej Surý

root@precise64:/home/vagrant# apt-get install php7.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0'
root@precise64:/home/vagrant# apt-get install php5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5.6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6'
```

Thank you

Comment: `apt update` first. You may also need to run: `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` Lastly, if you're doing a fresh install, why not start with php 7.1.

Comment: I've used `apt-get update` and `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` with `add-apt-repository`. Actually I need 5.6 to upgrade an application but none of them works

Comment: Can you upgrade to a more recent Ubuntu?

Comment: @mkaatman, yes!, that made the trick. As I'm not an expert in vagrant and followed their [example page](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/index.html). They use `hashicorp/precise64` which is **"A standard Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit box."**. Switching to `ubuntu/trusty64` (which is 2014's) works